# How to retreive dataLayer value in GA correctly

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm facing a problem while retreiving an event for GA. In GA, the **eventLabel** seems to find any problem with my dataLayer variables, as some of them are read as "undefined":

[image]

I've been researching my variables in code, but they seemed to be fine. And suddenly I found this while inspecting my GTM values:

[image]

The tag field was written in two lines and apparently "broken"! I supposed it was because of some sort of problem with my viewer, but I'm wondering if maybe that's the reason why my GA values are broken...

I checked length, and, when Iread Google documentation, the "eventLabel" tag can be 500 Bytes long:

[image]

And my texts are less than 500 Bytes long... So, what's the problem with my GA values? Is this "broken string" problem the responsible of the incorrect read of values in GA?

**EDIT:** This is the javascript behind. 
The push:

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event':'searchHome',
    'eventCategory':'Home',
    'eventAction':'search',
    'eventLabel': 'route|departureDate|returnDate|category|quantity|variant|people|' + resident + '|' + vehicle,
    'eventValue':'0'
});
```

Javascript to get the **resident** and **vehicle** variables (as they are the ones failing):

```
var vehicle = getTurismoValue($("#search-cars").val(), $("#search-cars option:selected").text(), $("#search-trailer").val());
var resident = getResidenciaValue($("#search-resident").val());
```

The functions behind:

```
function getTurismoValue(vehicle, literal, trailer) {
  try {
      if(vehicle != null && typeof vehicle !== "undefined") {
        if (vehicle.trim().length > 0) {
            return "Turismo|" + ((trailer.length > 0)?"si":"no");
        }
      }
      return "0";
  } catch (err) {
    return "0";
  }
};

function getResidenciaValue(resident) {
  try{
    if(resident != null && typeof resident !== "undefined") {
        if (resident.trim().length > 0) {
            return "peninsula";
        }
        return "extranjero";
    }
    return "0";
  } catch(err) {
    return "0";
  }
};
```

Does anybody see anything weird with this javascript? What's failing?

Comment: Can you please attach information about your Javascript variables, how you are populating event labels. Problem is that in some cases variable cannot receive value from your DOM, and it's writing `undefined` in your label

Comment: @VictorLeontyev I added the javascript used to get this values. Let's see if we see something wrong... Still breaking.